# YouTube metadata not validating on Twitter

Tags: validation, twitter, youtube, metadata

I have a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/WanderingDMs), for which almost all of the metadata cards fail to [validate on Twitter](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator). Therefore, when one of our video links get posted to Twitter, preview images and descriptions fail to appear.

Looking at the page source from YouTube, we can see that the videos that do validate have the following Twitter card meta tags, while the non-validating ones do not:

```
<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JkZ79cUy8UQ?list=PLiclN_BSxoe_K-gnfV7CCG0FTVGl5OX_W">
<meta name="twitter:player:width" content="1280">
<meta name="twitter:player:height" content="720">
```

I've come up totally empty from online searches for how to manually edit the YouTube metadata cards. If I test *other* people's YouTube videos, then I have yet to find one that fails to validate on Twitter.

How can I fix these missing meta twitter:player tags on our YouTube videos, so that our YouTube links will validate on Twitter (and thus show preview images)?

Comment: Note that in January 2021, there's a more general bug in this vein (not fixable by answer below). See: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/93583522?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by failing to have embedding permissions set on YouTube.

To fix for one video, in YouTube Creator Studio, edit that video and click on: Info & Settings > Advanced > Distribution Options > Allow Embedding (check the box).

To fix for all videos in bulk, again in Creator Studio, one can check-select all videos desired, then click Actions > More Actions > Embedding > Enable > Submit.

Note that metadata is cached on Twitter after it's first read from a YouTube link; therefore activating embedding won't immediately fix the missing previews on Twitter. To fix that, go to [Twitter's validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) and validate the updated YouTube page; this updates the cache at Twitter. This will update both old and new posts on Twitter with the preview description and image.